# jQuery - I'm populating an array from a text file. How can I make sure it's populated before executing any more code?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Here's the code that populates my array:

```
var subareas = [];

$.get( 'subareas.txt', function( data ) {

    subareas = data.split( ',' );
    console.log( subareas );
});
```

There are about 300~ entries in that .txt file — my question is: how can I make sure the array has finished building itself before I execute any more code?

The next step I want to write relies on the array being complete.

I've tried searching for an answer, and I turned up various results about promises and deferrals, but my jQuery comprehension isn't quite enough to get any of the examples I've seen working. Would really appreciate a little help!

Comment: By doing as you've written :)

Comment: This is an Ajax shorthand method of GET, So it will not wait for execution on next line. You can write the code within the $.get() or Write a function (e.g. function UseSubAreas(subareas)) and call the function within the $.get(.... UseSubAreas(subareas)) method

Comment: Haha, thank you so much Vijai! Such a simple solution and I've been trying to work it out for so long. Really appreciate your help.